# Stop application to write on Registry and Filesystem

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, registry

Suppose you have installed application X on your machine, not totally trustful. I would like to stop this application to make changes in my computer. My OS is Windows 7, but a solution on a neighbor like XP or Vista would be valid too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run it in a clean virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to do this in code? There exist several solutions like Thinapp, Molebox and some other which provide virtualization for an EXE, so that the wrapped EXE doesn't change the filesystem or registry. Take a look at them.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. Any other solution that be free and without virtualization?

Comment: Those applications don't use virtualization-as-we-know-it (in VMWAre or VirtualBox). They include a piece of code, which hooks file system and registry API calls right in the running process and redirects them to certain custom storage. In general, Microsoft offers an API (forgot it's name, sorry) that lets you do the same trick (hook Windows API calls and process them yourself), and this API is free for non-commercial use, but this requires writing quite a lot of code - you will need to hook about a dozen or two of complex functions.